# Django Rest framework group fields together

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model Offer with field like name ... and bandwidth_value and bandwidth_unit. I use Django REST framework class ModelSerializer to serialize my model.
I have :

```
{"id": 10,"max_devices":5,"bandwidth_value":"100.00","bandwidth_unit":"M"}
```

And I want to have ;

```
{"id": 10,"max_devices":5,"bandwidth":{"value":"100.00","unit":"M"}}
```

How can I do ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218141/nesting-fields-in-serialization-with-django-rest-framework.

Comment: There is an answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187476/django-rest-framework-how-to-nest-several-fields-in-a-serializer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom model serializer like below for your `Offer` model:

```
class Offer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                                                                                      
    class Meta:                                                                                                                         
        model = Offer
        fields = ('id', 'max_devices', 'bandwidth')                                                                                                                  

    # We add a custom field called "bandwidth",
    # which is served by a method in the serializer classs,
    # that returns the format you want.

    bandwidth = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_bandwidth')                                                              

    def get_bandwidth(self, obj):                                                                                                  
        return {'bandwidth': {'value': obj.bandwidth_value,
                             'unit': obj.bandwidth_unit}}
```